# How to speed up queries to a huge MySQL database (6m+ rows)

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, bigdata

As part of a project I've been gathering data from a number of sensors deployed in the field. The aim of this is to understand the performance of the devices and any potential problems or bugs that might be present.

I'm storing the data in a single table in a database with the columns id(primary), MAC_address, name, status, timestamp.

MAC_address is the one thing that is guaranteed to always be the same for a physical device and this is what I've been using mostly to extract information from the database.

My aim was to be able to extract data over a specific time period for a specific device whose MAC_address can be selected from a dropdown. Even doing a single SELECT DISTINCT query to get a list of unique MAC addresses was taking forever, but creating an index for that column seemed to speed it up. However, it still takes >30 seconds right now to extract any number of full rows from the database.

What is the best way to go about speeding up queries from a database this large?

Comment: Use the `EXPLAIN` keyword to observe query execution plans: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html  From there you can see where performance bottlenecks are and address them.

Comment: I would have thought having a table which lists devices (auto indexed ID, MAC_address, name etc.) and a table with readings ( ID, status, timestamp) would be a better structure for your data, a unique list of devices is just the records from the device table and no distinct needed.

Answer (score 0):

Single table...wrong.

One table describes each "device" (or "sensor").  It has an `id` which is, perhaps, a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (range of 0..65K -- you won't have more sensors than that?).  Note the MAC_address and name belong in this table.  This `id` is used on the other table...

Another table contains the `sensor_id`, `timestamp`, and `value`.  This table should have `PRIMARY KEY(sensor_id, timestamp)` and be ENGINE=InnoDB`.  Now it is very efficient for finding all the readings for one sensor over a period of time.

This completely avoids the `SELECT DISTINCT` since there are no dups in the first table.

If you are having a pulldown, then `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1-byte, 0..255) is probably plenty big.

OK, I have helped you with two `SELECTs`; what other ones will you have.  Keep in mind that performance is primarily based on the number of rows you need to touch.  And that counts the ones you reject.